# Why does it say: "Bad argument #1 to 'remove' (table expected, got nil)'"

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm trying to spawn random bullets from the side of the screen that the player has to dodge. When I try to do this, I get this error:

```
Error

main.lua:69: bad argument #1 to 'remove' (table expected, got nil)


Traceback

[C]: in function 'remove'
main.lua:69: in function 'update'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

I've tried to look around and see what I can do, but I can't find much. Sorry, if this is a newbie question, I'm REALLY new to Lua and Love2D.

Here is my entire code: (Error on line 69)

```
    function love.load()
        p = {}
        p.x = 330
        p.y = 330
        p.score = 0
        -------------
        b = {}
        b.size = 10
        b.cooldown = 150
        b.bullets = {}
        b.shoot = function()
            if b.cooldown <= 0 then
                b.cooldown = 50
                bullet = {}
                bullet.x = 0
                bullet.y = love.math.random(0, 690)
                table.insert(b.bullets, bullet)
            end
        end

    end


    function love.update(dt)
        p.score = p.score + 1
        b.cooldown = b.cooldown - 1
    -- movement of player (and the border)
        if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
            if p.y <= 0 then
                p.y = 0
            end

            p.y = p.y - 3
        end

        if love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
            if p.y >= 680 then
                p.y = 680
            end

            p.y = p.y + 3
        end

        if love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
            if p.x <= 0 then
                p.x = 0
            end

            p.x = p.x - 3
        end

        if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
            if p.x >= 680 then
                p.x = 680
            end
            p.x = p.x + 3
        end



    -- cooldown wait and shoot
        if b.cooldown <= 0 then
            b.shoot()
        end

    -- removes bullet when out of sight or moves bullets forward
        for i, b in ipairs(b.bullets) do
            if bullet.x >= 0 then
                table.remove(b.bullets, i)
            end
        bullet.x = bullet.x + 5
        end
    end

    function love.draw()
        love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(153, 76, 0)
        love.graphics.setColor(255, 0, 0)
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", p.x, p.y, 20, 20)
        love.graphics.print("p.x:" .. p.x .. " p.y:" .. p.y .. "    SCORE: " .. p.score .. "Cooldown: " .. b.cooldown, 0,0,0, 1, 1)

        --draw bullets
        love.graphics.setColor(255,0,0)
        for _,b in pairs(b.bullets) do
            love.graphics.rectangle("fill", bullet.y, bullet.x, bullet.size, bullet.size)
        end

    end
```

Comment: which is line 69

Comment: Be aware of how you're overwriting the `b` variable in your for loop (where you use `table.remove()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you that you have an error in line 69. The Lua interpreter complains that you put a nil value into the table.remove function instead of the expected table value.

So let's have a looik at your code:

```
-- removes bullet when out of sight or moves bullets forward
for i, b in ipairs(b.bullets) do
  if bullet.x >= 0 then
    table.remove(b.bullets, i)
  end
  bullet.x = bullet.x + 5
end
```

You iterate over table `b.bullets` and store the current value in a variable `b`, local to the for loop. That means inside the for loop you no longer have access to your global table `b`, which contains the table `bullets`.

As your local `b` does not have any member named `bullets`, `b.bullets` is a nil value inside the for loop.

Using table.remove on a table you're iterating over with ipairs is also not going to work. Let's say you have a table like this:

```
a = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

and you do this

```
for i,v in ipairs(a) do
  table.remove(a, i)
end
```

In the first run using index 1 you'll remove 1 which will result in a new table `{2,3,4,5}`.
In the next cycle using index 2 you'll remove 3 instead of 2 as 3 is now your second element. After removing 3 your table is `{2,4,5}`. Next round with index 3 you'll remove 5 from the table. As this was the last element in your table the loop is done after 3 iterations instead of 5 and you'll end up with 2 elements left in the table instead of 0.

There are various other issues with your code but I suggest you first make sure that you understand the scope of variables in Lua befor you continue.